# Set counter in xsl to set the tabIndex

Tags: javascript, html, xslt-1.0

I Have written some XSL code which reads an XML file and creates input elements of type text for each child node. Consider the following XML file, for node c two input boxes would be created like

Label(com 1) :input box--------------------- Label (com 2) :input box

There can be any number of child nodes under node c and any number of nodes like c. If one row on HTML page is filled for child nodes under c then another row would be created. I want the user to be able to move from one input box to next input box in the same row, not to the input box on next row.

I want to set the tab index for each input element generated using XSL.I need to count the number of child nodes under one parent node so that I set the tab index for child nodes of next parent element.

```
<Base>          
            <C>
                <Label>Af</Label>
                <Column>
                    <Label>Com 1</Label>
                    <Max>200</Max>                  
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Label>Com 2</Label>
                    <max>100</max>                  
                </Column>
            </C>

            <D>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>40</max>   
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>340</max>                      
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>340</max>                      
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>

                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>

                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>

                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>A</Label>
                        <max>40</max>

                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>B</Label>
                        <max>40</max>

                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>C</Label>
                        <max>40</max>

                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>D</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column>
                        <Label>E</Label>
                        <max>40</max>                       
                    </Column>
                </Row>
                <GColumn>
            </Base>
```

As XSL being a functional language I couldn't find a way to set a variable and increment it after one execution for for-each loop. Need some help to maintain the count of elements based upon which I can set the tabindex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to count elements in a loop, you can get an element's index in a For-Each loop with `position()`

```
<xsl:variable name="itempos" select="position()"/>
```

And get the total number of child's elements with `count()`

```
<xsl:variable name="itemcount" select="count(/Base/c/*)"/>
```